# SELECTstatement with a variable WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, case, where-clause

I am trying to create a select statement with an interchangeable where statement within it i have got the 2 attempts which do not work to show you to try and understand what i am trying to achieve

the variable `@holidayType` determines what type of holiday the user has booked and i want that to also determine which `WHERE` statement is run

below is my first attempt

```
    IF @HolidayType = 'P'
        BEGIN
           WHERE    Holidays.Type <> 'A'
           AND  Holidays.Type <> 'DE'
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @HolidayType = 'A'
                BEGIN
                    WHERE   Holidays.Type <> 'P'
                    AND     Holidays.Type <> 'DE'
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    WHERE Holidays.status <> 'DE' 
                END
        END
```

Below is my second attempt (a bit clearer)

```
    WHERE
    (
    CASE @HolidayType
        WHEN 'A' THEN (Holidays.Type <> 'P' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE')
        WHEN 'P' THEN (Holidays.Type <> 'A' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE')
        WHEN 'F' THEN (Holidays.status <> 'DE')
    END
    )
```

the select before both of them are relatively simple it is just the addition of the `Where` statement that is proving difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose the following solution. Perhaps for the author will be clearer because it is close to his query:

```
WHERE
    (
    CASE @HolidayType 
        WHEN 'A' THEN CASE WHEN (Holidays.Type <> 'P' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        WHEN 'P' THEN CASE WHEN (Holidays.Type <> 'A' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        WHEN 'F' THEN CASE WHEN (Holidays.status <> 'DE') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    END = 1
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE
  (@HolidayType = 'A' AND Holidays.Type <> 'P' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE')
  OR 
   (@HolidayType = 'P' AND Holidays.Type <> 'A' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE')
  OR 
  (@HolidayType = 'F' AND Holidays.status <> 'DE')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
 WHERE (@HolidayType = 'A' AND Holidays.Type <> 'P' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE') OR
       (@HolidayType = 'P' AND Holidays.Type <> 'A' AND Holidays.Type <> 'DE') OR
       (@HolidayType = 'F' AND Holidays.status <> 'DE')
```

Comment: Hi, after this statement i forgot to mention there is going to be a additional and statement with some extra rules would it merge okay (like order wise and things)

Comment: I'm getting an error at the minute where it doesn't seem to be working i will update when it is working :) thanks